# How to diagrammatically represent High Value Added

Tags: information-graphics, presentation-design, diagram

High Value Added Manufacturing is a manufacturing model whereby the sale price of the end product is considerably higher than the production cost.

And I have no idea where to begin representing this diagrammatically. I need something that's not immediately 'chart-like' because that wouldn't fit very well in the particular presentation format. I'm totally stuck for ideas; can you guys help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about an illustration of a factory, with on one side:

- materials going in
- a little pile of coins going out

and on the other side:

- product going out
- a great big pile of coins coming in

Comment: shaft going in, rainbows coming out :)

Comment: @horatio not sure I want something that'd be so easily attributed to sex... lol

Comment: I want to avoid piles of coins because I dont want the presenter to look like he's profiteering, but I like your idea

Comment: Okay, so the client pitched in and opted for a pile of coins... So err, you win!